# Got an Error in existing React js app npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ahsan Raza\Desktop\myapp\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Ahsan Raza\Desktop\myapp\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ahsan Raza\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-04T07_52_05_804Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Hi, welcome on S.O. please post your log in the question (you'll find the log in the path specified by npm execution - last line)

Answer (score 0):

> no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Ahsan
> Raza\Desktop\myapp\package.json'

looks like you are running it on a wrong directory or there is no package.json for some reason